# Wordpress custom rss or json feed

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rss, feed

It is possible to make wordpress output rss or json with last 10 posts from all categories with 10 or more posts published?

Something like that or similar:

```
<categorie>
    <title>News</title>
    <slug>news</slug>
    <lastposts>  
        <item>
            <title>New 1</title>
            <url>http://website.com/new1</url>
            <thumb>http://website.com/thumbnail_new1.jpg</thumb>
        </item>

        <item>
            <title>New 2</title>
            <url>http://website.com/new2</url>
            <thumb>http://website.com/thumbnail_new2.jpg</thumb>
        </item>

        ...

    </lastposts>
</categorie>

<categorie>
    <title>Other</title>
    <slug>other</slug>
    <lastposts>
        <item>
            <title>Other 1</title>
            <url>http://website.com/other1</url>
            <thumb>http://website.com/thumbnail_other1.jpg</thumb>
        </item>

        <item>
            <title>Other 2</title>
            <url>http://website.com/other2</url>
            <thumb>http://website.com/thumbnail_other2.jpg</thumb>
        </item>

        ...

    </lastposts>
</categorie>

...
```

I've already try with `http://www.example.com/?cat=42,43&feed=rss2` but it doesn't display 10 posts per categorie.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Try this [tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/).